# How to execute same function on subsciption and error callback in rxjs to wrap loading state, i.e. show loading before Observable and hide afterwards?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

### Use case

I have some loading that starts in an RxJS Observable and I want to end/wrap that loading when finished.
Th observable either returns an error or it returns new data to load.

Finishing can mean both the Observable returns an error or it triggers a new value.

**Edit:** In the variant below, I additionally have another Observable that triggers the whole loading process.

### MVE

You can trivially implement it by duplicating the code, but that is

```js
const {
  from,
  concat,
  throwError
} = rxjs;


concat(
  from([1, 2, 3]),
  throwError("fail")
).subscribe((x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  },
  (x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.7/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Basically I search for an operator or so that would remove the code duplication in the above example.

### With loading showing

Showing loading of course happens before, e.g. in a `tap`:

```js
const {
  from,
  concat,
  throwError,
  pipe,
  tap
} = rxjs;


concat(
  from([1, 2, 3]),
  throwError("fail")
).pipe(
   tap(() => console.log("show loading"))
).subscribe((x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  },
  (x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.7/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Uff `tap` i.e. showing the loading of course also not happens on error.

### However, this is the real example

However, in my real implementation that won't happen, because I merge two Observables and have a trigger Observable that triggers the whole process:

```js
const {
  from,
  concat,
  throwError,
  pipe,
  tap,
  switchMap,
  Subject
} = rxjs;

// this is the trigger to load stuff (in Angular triggered from the outside component e.g.)
loadData$ = new Subject();

loadData$ //< <- this is irrelevant now and just the trigger
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("show loading")), // <-- show loading when/before data loading starts
    switchMap(() => {
      return concat(
        from([4, 5, 6]),
        throwError("fail")
      )
    })
  ).subscribe((x) => { // <-- end loading when/after data loading ends or fails
      console.log("loading end", x);
    },
    (x) => {
      console.log("loading end", x);
    }
  )


loadData$.next(); // just trigger for testing here
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.7/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

### Tries

- I tried the [`finalize`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator, but that only triggers on completion (whether error or not), so that is not an option here.
- I guess the `complete` callback would thus have the same effect.

### Okay, I see problems...

While writing this, admittedly, I see that if the Observable fails, no new values may be emitted. (Or may that be the case, actually?)

```js
const {
  from,
  concat,
  throwError,
  of
} = rxjs;

concat(
  from([1, 2, 3]),
  throwError("fail"),
  of ("another value") // <-- is not triggered
).subscribe((x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  },
  (x) => {
    console.log("loading end", x);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.7/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Interne Referenz: !10155

Answer (score 0):

Your update is correct. `finalize` is the way to go here.
From rxjs docs (https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) you can see the following quote:

> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.

This means if an error is thrown, `finalize` is called. This observable will not emit anything else afterwards, so the state is the same as completed.